# A different approach for using php for modularity purposes

Tags: php, html, css, web-applications

So I recent got into learning php and now I find I typically follow this weird design pattern for building webpages but I don't know if its actually as smart as I think it is or it just a jumble of garbage.

I basically use php to load the header and footer of a website, since every webpage has the same on on a website generally. I then use php to load the html for center content of each page.

I feel that using this method I can create new web pages fast since the "template" of header and footer is already created and that it is easier for managing a website because the code is essentially like having interchangeable blocks of smaller code that just get swapped out.

Does anyone else use this kind of method? are there similar patterns that are more efficient.

Comment: Yes, plenty of people have written template engines/frameworks that work upon the modularity you've discovered. Some simple, some horrifically complex. There are a lot and worth googling for. Explore!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good coding practice. I always build websites in this way, too, so that I can add content and get it live quickly while building the `Django` back-end.

I think that I do it in the reverse, though. Each of my pages, (say, `index.php`), has an `include` to both the `header` and `footer`.

A super helpful thing I wrote is a short `PHP` script that determines your current directory, so that I can always type links in the same way on every page.

This is the code:

```
<?php

//This function generates a string of the page URL
function curPageURL() {
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
//We then store the URL as a string
$url = curPageURL();
//And split the string up everytime there is a backslash
$pieces = explode('/', $url);

//Each backslash corresponds to a directory, so we can now use this to compute
//what we need to prepend to the links.

//Root
if (count($pieces) == 2)
    $root = '';
else if (count($pieces) == 3)
$root = '../';
else if (count($pieces) == 4)
$root = '../../';

//Finally, we include the header file.
include($root . 'header.php');
?>
```

This way, all links on the webpage take that same form.

```
<a href="<?php echo $root; ?>business/">
```

This also has special use on a `404` page, as that page will appear in whatever directory you happen to `404` in!

Answer (score 0):

This is basicaly the way all developpers start, your are on the right track, but i might suggest you soon switch to a full fledged templating system, a MVC framework or a CMS that already has those features built-in for you.

You can usually even use all 3 at once or the CMS will provide the other components themselves...

Good luck with your learning!